# Partial view data not showing MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I believe that this is a problem with my HTML / CSS code as those are my clear weak points. I have a partial view that I only want shown when someone pick an option from the drop down box. This partial view (_ChampionStats) is being loaded, I can put a break point in there and see it being hit, but the data is never shown. Any suggestions?

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@using LoLBuild.Models
@model ChampionViewModel

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Choose Your Champion</h2>
<div class="inputblock" style="clear: both;width:100%;">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model)
    @Html.DropDownList("ChampionList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ChampionSelectList, new { @onchange="location = Index/this.value;" })
</div>

<div id="ChampionStats">
    @if (ViewBag.SelectedChampion > 0)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_ChampionStats", Model);

    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ChampionList").change(function() {
            var strSelected = "";
            $("#ChampionList option:selected").each(function() {
                strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
            });
            var url = "/Champion/Index/" + strSelected;

            $.post(url, function(data) {
                // do something if necessary
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Partial View (_ChampionStats.cshtml):**

```
@using LoLBuild.Models
@model ChampionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ChampionStats";
}
    <h3>Partial Rendered Successfully</h3>
    @Html.TextBox("Health:", Model.BeginHealth, new {style = "width: 100px;"})
```

**EDIT:** I noticed that there's an error in the console, yet I'm not sure what it means. This is the error:

```
GET http://localhost:49219/jquery.js 404 (Not Found) localhost:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: Index is not defined localhost:36
onchange
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
@Html.RenderPartial
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: I attempted this, but it yielded no results. I was still able to put a break point within the partial view and see that it was in fact being called and the view being found but nothing appeared on the screen. Here's the code change that I made to the Index view:

<div>
    @if (ViewBag.SelectedChampion > 0) 
    { 
        Html.RenderPartial("_ChampionStats", Model); 
    }
</div>

Answer (score 0):

a 404 implies that the path `http://localhost:49219/jquery.js` doesn't exist. The default location for jquery would be the scripts folder, and containing the version i.e. `http://localhost:49219/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js`. you can use the tools in f12 of your browser to check if the file was found or not, i.e. network in chrome, or fiddler will give you more info
Tim

Comment: Yeah that was one of the errors, it's solved now. Unfortunately, I just don't know what to put here: new { @onchange="location = **Index/this.value**;" }